# Scheduled snapshots wont run Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, snapshot, schedule

I have configured a snapshot schedule for one of my disks on Compute Engine, but after the scheduled time (way after), no snapshot is listed on the snapshots section.

I ran a manual snapshot with the same settings (snapshot-2 in the attached image) and it ran fine.

Is there some place else the schedule snaps are saved? How can I check them? Or did do something wrong?

Below are a couple os screenshots to help.

[Scheduled snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hovP3.png) / 
[Snapshots list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiJGr.png)

Comment: Schedule snapshots are regional resources and you can access from Cloud Console but it seems for some reason snapshot schedule did not work for you. It require an in depth investigation of the affected project to identify the root cause. I would recommend to file a defect report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491456&template=1161077)

Answer (score 5):

I guess the issue is resolved now. It is working fine now. I also tried to do a small video on procedure to show how scheduled snapshot works... The YouTube link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxL6s7eURrk

Answer (score 1):

The Product team have identified the issue and are working to roll out a fix. Unfortunately, I'm unable to provide an ETA. You may see the public [issue thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/124654199) for more details.